# Arduino industrial 101 digital pins

Tags: pins, 101

I don't see anything that has been clear about which digital pins map to which physical ones. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be a big help.

For exampleThrough trial and error, i've found that if i set digital pin 3 in the Arduino IDE, it is mapped to D0 on J6, but surely this is documented somewhere?

Comment: I just Google "Arduino  Industrial 101", tab **Images** and found what you are looking for. Pinout for other Arduinos can be a good starting point, I guess

Comment: We must have different search results, because that was the second thing i did and didn't see what i was looking for, but thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what i was looking for on the arduino github repository.

Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/